Caesar's Cipher in JavaScript: How to compare two strings and pull unmatching parts out of the string
I am working on trying to figure out how to write Caesar's Cipher (encryption/decryption).  Essentially, a string is defined, then the program evaluates the string and adds a letter shift to each character in the string to produce a new encrypted string.  If given a string that is just one word, I have it working.  But when a single space, numbers, or special characters are entered into my string I either get no output or the spaces are treated like a 'z'.  I have been working on this for several days and cannot seem to figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated.
Just so people are aware, this is for a class I am taking.  I am stuck and the class is online so I have limited resources when I get stuck.  If you don't feel comfortable helping, I understand.  I don't know what else to do at this point.
I have a string with the alphabet, which I want to compare to my defined string with a message in it.  I have tried using a for loop with an if statement using indexOf, includes, test, match and I don't remember all the others.  Nothing gives me the results I am looking for. I tried asking ChatGPT just to see if I could understand.  The program works from ChatGPT, but it provided the charCode and fromCharCode, which I do not understand and I have a feeling that is not the best method for someone that is a beginning programmer.


const shift = 3;
//const alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
const alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
const partyLocation = "garden";
const plainMessage = 'Where will the party take place in 2024?';

let newString = [];
//index = plainMessage.indexOf(' ');
for (i = 0; i < plainMessage.length; i++) {
  newString = [];
  if (alphabet.includes(plainMessage)) {
    newString += [i];
    console.log(newString);
    console.log('hello');
  } else
    newString += [i];
  newString += ["g"];
}

console.log(newString);
console.log(alphabet.includes(plainMessage));
console.log(plainMessage.length);

function encryptLetter(letter, shift) {
  const index = alphabet.indexOf(letter.toLowerCase());
  const alphabetLength = alphabet.length;
  const newIndex = (index + shift) % alphabetLength;
  const newLetter = alphabet[newIndex];
  return newLetter;
}

const encryptResult = encryptLetter('B', 3);
console.log(`The encrypted letter is ${encryptResult}`);




What are you expecting alphabet.indexOf to return for elements not in that list (such as numbers, spaces, punctuation)?

My thought was to use indexOf in an if statement.  But, I don't know how to add the spaces, numbers or special characters in the exact location in the sentence in the output.  I tried using an if statement with indexOf != -1.  But I am not sure how else to use that statment in this situation.

A lot of the console.logs were just to see if the code is even executing how I expected.

If they're not meant to be shifted, you'd compare to negative 1 and return letter. Otherwise, do you have examples of outputs you expect that have characters other than letters?

In the working portion, the following was run:   Input (Garden, 3); Output: The encrypted message is jdughq

But that only works if it is one word.  If I use special characters, numbers or spaces, the program no longer works.

You've not provided any examples of what you are expecting non-letters to do. How would 2024 be encoded? Just as is, or something else?

My bad, I didn't catch that.  All non-letters are returned to the original value.  So, the previous example:  Input: (Garden 2024, 3) => Output: jdughq 2024

So, in the encrypt function, you can check if (index == -1) { return letter;}... I'm not sure how you're calling that function in any loop over the original string, though

Why are you initializing newString as an array rather than a string? += is converting it to a string. And there's no need to put the += argument in square brackets.

You also shouldn't reset it inside the for loop.

Thank you for the help.  I did get this part figured out.
